# Is there a way to fix an index error in a bubble sort?

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I am trying to write a bubble sort in vb and i have the algorithm right but it always says 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' which i do not know how to fix. I will put the code below and any help will be good.

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim unsorted() As Integer = {17, 19, 12, 10, 15, 20}
    Dim n As Integer = unsorted.Length
    Dim swapped As Boolean = True
    Dim temp
    Dim list As String = ""

    While n > 0 And swapped = True
        For a = 0 To n - 1
            If unsorted(a) > unsorted(a + 1) Then
                temp = unsorted(a)
                unsorted(a) = unsorted(a + 1)
                unsorted(a + 1) = temp
                swapped = True
            End If
        Next
    End While
    For Each number In unsorted
        number &= list & " "
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(list)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? What is the index that is out of bounds? What are the valid bounds? What do you think the index should be? You need to actually debug your code, not just read it and then look at the end result when you run it. Set breakpoints, step through the code and examine the state at each step.

Comment: That said, just a little though should be enough. If you are comparing elements to the next element, what is the last element that you can do that for? Does the last element have a next element? I think that it's safe to assume that you have not properly compared your code to your algorithm because that algorithm wouldn't do that.

Comment: Consider this line of code. `If unsorted(a) > unsorted(a + 1) Then` When `a` reaches `n - 1` it is the highest index in the array. When you try to refer at the element at `unsorted(a + 1)` the index at `a + 1` is out of range because `a` is the highest index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed, your implementation of the bubble sort algorithm seems to be a bit flawed; I see some problems in your code, too.

code:

a is not declared

temp should be an integer

algorithm:

'n' is the length of your array, therefore it will be always > 0 (while condition)

'swapped' is declared as 'true', and never set to false, therefore it will be always 'true'

if a comparison results in a no-swap (i.e., item(a) < item(a+1)), then 'swapped' should be set to 'false'

after a swap, you should exit the for loop, and restart from a=0

hope this helps,
Luca

Comment: "a" don't need to be declared since it's in `for` loop. You can directly put any value as just to count the index. Secondly, the "temp" is already an integer, he didn't specify any datatype, hence, it's implicitly converted during assignment `temp = unsorted(a)` which is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work for you:

```
Private unsorted() As Byte = {17, 19, 12, 10, 15, 20}

Sub Main()
    Dim temp As Byte

    For pass = 1 To unsorted.Length - 1
        For i = 0 To unsorted.Length - 2
            If unsorted(i) > unsorted(i + 1) Then
                temp = unsorted(i)
                unsorted(i) = unsorted(i + 1)
                unsorted(i + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next i
    Next pass

    Dim output As String = ""

    For i = 0 To unsorted.Length - 1
        output &= unsorted(i).ToString + vbNewLine
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(output)

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Here's the result:

[image: Bubble Sort Algorithm Success]

Enjoy the Bubble Sort.